# How to get checked value(values) from checkbox and save into database using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get checked elements from checkbox and save them into the database
How to check which of these checkboxes are checked and where to save them before the database?
I'm using AngularJS

**This is my HTML form:**

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="album.selected" value={{album.name}} />
     {{album.name}}
   </li>
 </ul>
 <button type='button' ng-click="save1()">Save</button><br>
 Saved results:<br>
 {{albumNameArray[0]}}
```

**and AngularJS code:**

```
$scope.albums = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sell'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'buy'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'pko'
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'rko'
  }
];

$scope.save1 = function() {
  $scope.albumNameArray = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album) {
    if (album.selected) $scope.albumNameArray.push(album.name);
    for(var i=0;i<albumNameArray.length;i++) {
      alert(albumNameArray[i]);
    }
  });
}
```